# Can a subclass of Netty's SimpleChannelInboundHandler be Sharable?

Tags: java, netty

I'm creating a subclass of the `SimpleChannelInboundHandler` which keeps no state and is entirely threadsafe. I'm wondering if it's safe to make it Sharable? The docs seem to be silent on the matter, and while it would be nice to reuse the object, I'd rather not run into nasty race conditions later.

Comment: I think not being able to use sharability is a special case and by default it's always possible. You can see the [source code](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/transport/src/main/java/io/netty/channel/SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java), it doesn't store any information that could cause problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is save to make sub-classes @Sharable as long as there is no state that you keep in the sub-class and that is not thread-safe.